# assign objects to dynamic lists in r

Tags: r

I have a nested loops which produce outputs that I want to store in list objects with dynamic names. A toy example of this would look as follows:

```
set.seed(8020)
names<-sample(LETTERS,5,replace = F)

for(n in names)
{
  #Create the list
  assign(paste0("examples_",n),list())

  #Poulate the list
  get(paste0("examples_",n))[[1]]<-sample(100,10)
  get(paste0("examples_",n))[[2]]<-sample(100,10)
  get(paste0("examples_",n))[[3]]<-sample(100,10)
}
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the error:

```
  Error in get(paste0("examples_", n))[[1]] <- sample(100, 10) : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I have tried all kind of `assign`, `eval`, `get` type of functions to parse the object, but haven't had any luck

Comment: You can't use `get` and then assign.  Instead you can try with `assign` itself

Comment: I have tried `assign(paste0("examples_",n)[[1]],sample(100,10))`, but as soon as you want to assign the second item as `assign(paste0("examples_",n)[[2]],sample(100,10))` I get a `subscript out of bounds` error. Currently my work around is to create a static `list()` assign the samples and then once populated i use `assign(paste0("examples_",n), static_list)` to 'transfer` the data before starting the loop again. Just feel like can be a better more memory efficient way

Comment: It looks like you are creating a bunch of separate objects in your workspace and then doing the same or similar operation to them. That really what a list is supposed to support. You approach is considered "ugly" by experienced R programmers. Make a single list of those named "leaves" or "nodes" and then iterate over that single list with `lapply`. (Also. don't use the name `names` for a data-object. It's an essential R function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment with a worked example:

```
 examples <- vector(mode="list", length=length(names) )
 names(examples) <- names  # please change that to mynames 
                           # or almost anything other than `names`
 examples <- lapply( examples, function(L) {L[[1]] <- sample(100,10)
                         L[[2]] <- sample(100,10)
                         L[[3]] <- sample(100,10); L}  )
# Top of the output:
> examples
$P
$P[[1]]
 [1] 34 49  6 55 19 28 72 42 14 92

$P[[2]]
 [1] 97 71 63 59 66 50 27 45 76 58

$P[[3]]
 [1] 94 39 77 44 73 15 51 78 97 53


$F
$F[[1]]
 [1] 12 21 89 26 16 93  4 13 62 45

$F[[2]]
 [1] 83 21 68 74 32 86 52 49 16 13

$F[[3]]
 [1] 14 45 40 46 64 85 88 28 53 42
```

This mode of programming does become more natural over time. It gets you out of writing clunky for-loops all the time. Develop your algorithms for a single list-node at a time and then use `sapply` or `lapply` to iterate the processing.

Comment: Thanks for this illustration. I have found that in simple examples my coding has changed to this style, but in nested examples (as is in my real application) an automatic switch to the `for` loop mentality kicks in. This is much more efficient